# Как сделать историю действий?

Tags: c#

Пользователь может ложить деньги на свой счёт (класс Account) и я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы это сохранялось в историю по хронологии "Дата - Действие". И ещё хотел бы узнать, как сделать чтобы она автоматически чистилась, допустим, каждый месяц? Спасибо за внимание!

```
public class Account
{

    public event EventHandler<AccountEventArgs> Notify;
    private List<string> history;
    public int Sum { get; private set; }

    public Account(int sum)
    {
        Sum = sum;
        history = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Put(int sum)
    {
        Sum += sum;
        var args = new AccountEventArgs($"На счёт положено {sum}");
        Notify?.Invoke(this, args);
        history.Add(args.Message);
    }

    public void GetHistory()
    {
        foreach (var value in history)
        {
            Notify?.Invoke(this, new AccountEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Класс аргументов события:

```
public class AccountEventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public AccountEventArgs(string msg)
    {
        Message = msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то давно я делал [пример виуальной реализации](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564124/12888024) "пуш" уведомлей в WPF приложении. Возможно вам помогут какие-то механики из того примера. Единственное скажу, что проверку на истечение времени для чистки можно сделать при добавлении очередной записи. То есть, добавляете запись - проверяете старые и удаляете в этот же момент. И вы странно используете событие в методе `GetHistory()` если у вас в логе будет 1000 записей, вы 1000 раз вызовете событие? Сколько времени будут выполняться обработчики этого события? Не проще просто вернуть список?

Comment: Какоц тип приложения? Если WinForms, советую вам рассмотреть коллекцию `BindingList`, если WPF - `ObservableCollection`. Внутри есть события, которые нативно поддерживаются интерфейсом (`DataGrid(View)`), и на которые вы можете подписать свои обработчики.

Comment: @aepot а если это веб?) или консоль?)))

Comment: @return или сервер, или .NET Framework 2.0? :))))